# Поиск подстроки с помощью re.sub (python)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```py
https://yandex.ru/catalog/dlya_detey_i_ne_tolko?spcSecProductsWhatProd=sneki,fruktovoe_pyure&page=1
```

Из неё с помощью регулярных выражения и библиотеки `re.sub` необходимо получить строку `sneki,fruktovoe_pyure`. Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Взять и сделать. А если серьёзно то как вы это собираетесь сделать если ссылка у вас невалидная?

Comment: Зачем вам валидная ссылка? Это пример, приближенный к реальному

Comment: А валидная ссылка нужна,  чтобы не мучить регулярные выражения. Для работы с ссылками есть готовый модуль, чтобы получать хост, путь, параметры query и прочее

Comment: Не надо никого и ничего мучить. Если будет подсказка по этому адресу, для другого я уже сам смогу составить код по аналогии

Comment: В приоритете использовать именно регулярку

Comment: в вопросах про регулярки на "надо получить" самая главная информация не ЧТО надо получить, а ПОЧЕМУ надо получить именно это. Но большинство почему-то только сообщает ЧТО, хотя на самом деле это вообще не важно. Важно - ПОЧЕМУ. Как ты узнал, что нужно получить именно sneki,fruktovoe_pyure?

Comment: Это значение параметра spcSecProductsWhatProd, оно мне и нужно

Comment: `(?<=spcSecProductsWhatProd=)[^&]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

link = "https://yandex.ru/catalog/dlya_detey_i_ne_tolko?spcSecProductsWhatProd=sneki,fruktovoe_pyure&page=1"

result = re.sub(r"\S+spcSecProductsWhatProd=(?P<result>\S*)\&\S*", r"\g<result>", link)

print(result)
```

> sneki,fruktovoe_pyure

Answer (score 0):

все-таки покажу, как можно достать данные с помощью стандартного модуля `urllib`, хотя предпочтения ТС отдаются регулярке, авось пригодится

```py
from urllib import parse

url = "https://yandex.ru/catalog/dlya_detey_i_ne_tolko?spcSecProductsWhatProd=sneki,fruktovoe_pyure&page=1"

qs = parse.urlparse(url).query
dict_ = parse.parse_qs(qs)
```

Что по итогу содержит `dict_`

```py
{'spcSecProductsWhatProd': ['sneki,fruktovoe_pyure'], 'page': ['1']}
```

Логика

1. Забираем строку, которая содержит `query` после вопросительного знака в ссылке
2. Дальше получаем словарь со всеми значениями, которые содержит это строка
3. Используем словарь как что-то обычное по своему усмотрению

Comment: Спасибо! В будущем обязательно пригодится

Comment: @oblako_123 на здоровье) не понятно только, почему вы выбираете писать лишнюю логику, когда этот функционал уже реализован из коробки. Плюс добавлю, что регулярные выражения интуитивно не понятны и сильно тормозят по скорости. Я бы даже воспользовался бы стандартными методами строки, чем использовать регулярки. Регулярки хороши для всякого рода поиска/замены по шаблонам, но точно не в этом случае. Но выбор за вами